# How to send data back to Android app from django rest framework using asynchttp?

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, http-post, android-async-http

**Model.py**

```
 class Server(models.Model):
 label = models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True)  #compare this
 upload1 = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
 Image1 = models.TextField(upload1, null=True)

 class Android(models.Model):
 label=models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True) #with this
 imagestring=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
 returnlabel=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

So in my serializer class i am comparing labels from Android model and server model in (def get_returnlabel),and i want to return this label back to my android app.Any suggestons on how to do it.On my android app I am using async http.

**Serializer.py**

```
   class FoodSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
   model=Server
   fields=('url','label','Image1','upload1')

 class AndroidSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = Android
    fields = ('label', 'imagestring', 'returnlabel') (<--returnlabel back to android app)

 #Compare label from Server and Android

 def get_return_label(self, obj):
       queryset = Server.objects.filter( labelServer=obj.label)
       queryset_serializer = FoodSerializers( queryset, many=True, read_only=True)      
       return queryset_serializer.data
```

**Views.py**

```
  class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
            queryset = Server.objects.all()
            serializer_class =FoodSerializers

  class Androids(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset =Android.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AndroidSerializers
```

Comment: In `get_return_label(self, obj)` where would `obj` come from? Would this be looked up from the incoming request?

Comment: Get_return_label line 2 .labelserver=obj.label so yes..please help me out here really desperatr

Comment: Ok so to clarify, you're essentially wanting to expose `get_return_label()` so that your Android application can retrieve the data from it remotely?

Comment: yes.Can u help me out?

Comment: I'll try. So when your Android app makes a request to `get_return_label()`, what parameters will it send? Perhaps you could post that code if you have written it.

Comment: Is it possible for me to send u my code on ur email so that you can have a brief look at it?

Comment: If not then i will send my android code here

Comment: Could you post your code to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/login) or [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Sure i will post it onpastebin..gimme 5 mins

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pekgn2h1  (Main Activity)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fCzbV203   (FoodAppClient)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hLHtw0rW (RecognizeFood)

Comment: do u want me to send u the xml as well?

Comment: Thakyou for helping me out. really in need of help

Comment: I tried applying the first method and it keeps showing me that Method\GET\not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, and that you're basically asking how you would return the output from `get_return_label()` back to your Android client, then you should just be able to create an [extra action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) in your viewset for that. You'd need to relocate `get_return_label()` to the viewset first.

For example:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response

class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodSerializers

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def get_return_label(self, request):
        obj = request.data  # The RecognizingFood object posted by the client

        queryset = Server.objects.filter(label=obj['label'])
        queryset_serializer = FoodSerializers(queryset, many=True, read_only=True)      
        return Response(queryset_serializer.data)
```

To access it, you'd use the existing URL of `FoodViewSet` appended with `/get_return_label/`

The alternative is to create a [dedicated view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views) end point:

```
from rest_framework import views

class GetReturnLabelView(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        obj = request.data  # The RecognizingFood object posted by the client

        queryset = Server.objects.filter(label=obj['label'])
        queryset_serializer = FoodSerializers(queryset, many=True, read_only=True)      
        return Response(queryset_serializer.data)

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Server.objects.filter(label=request.data['label'])
        queryset_serializer = FoodSerializers(queryset, many=True, read_only=True)      
        return Response(queryset_serializer.data)
```

And map that in your `urls.py`:

```
path(r'get_return_label', views.GetReturnLabelView.as_view())
```

Comment: Thanks but what changes would i need to make on my android code to see wether i am getting the values back

Comment: Both approaches assume your android client is making a `POST` request (from what I could establish from looking at your code). If you want to make a `GET` request, you'll need to update the `methods` list in approach 1, and add a `get()` function in approach 2. Your existing `LOG` statements in the `onSuccess()` callback should print out the values of the response you get back. Just make sure that your logging system is switched to log at the correct level (e.g. DEBUG) so that you actually see these messages.

Comment: but what do i put in get method?

Comment: can u help me here as well..so sorry

Comment: On mobile now but will look again later.

Comment: Thankyou..will wait for your response

Comment: Are u avaliable now?

Comment: I've added an example `get()` method. That would assume you'd call the URL as `http://server/get_return_label?label=some_label`. Sorry if I can't be of much more help.

Comment: Thankyou sir still facing some issues but i hope i will be able to resolve it somehow..:)

Comment: cause i cant seem to figure out which method to update in android